# SSIS - Check if URL is valid

Tags: sql-server, ssis-2012

In SSIS [VS 2012], is there a way to check to see if a URL is valid before continuing with the loading process? If possible I would like to separate a list of URLs between valid and invalid, and only load the valid URLs. I already have a package created loading a list of URLs, but I'm receiving errors in the history from the invalid URLs and I would like to clean up those errors by filtering out the invalid URLs. Examples would be greatly appreciated! Thanks!

Comment: The best option is to do that in a programming language, java, c# etc. Read each url then check if it's valid, output all valid to a clean file for ssis to load. You may be able to do that in a script task, but most work is still programming, so better leave it to a programming language.

Comment: what your package does after loading the URLs? How your package gets errors in the history from the invalid URLs ?

Comment: I'm using the URLs in my XML source. So when the source comes across a URL that doesn't exist it fails with the error "The URL was unable to read the XML data: (404) Not Found". I have the package setup where if it fails it will update the audit table stating that URL was invalid. However, my architect reviews the package history and those errors are still present, even though it was handled. If I could check if a URL was valid before loading I could get rid of those errors.

Comment: Hmm I actually like your design over the alternatives as yours is clear and works with SSIS functionality alone.  Other alternatives will require you to create a script task and/or script component and test the url by attempting to connect to it.  I do do this and I did run into an issue maxing out threads connecting to a single website when using the script component so I had to move it to script task so I could control concurrency.  I would leave your design as is based on your comment.

Answer (score 1):

I was able to achieve the above by using the script task component along with the following C# piece of code. I passed my URL through a variable and was able to see if it was valid or invalid. I then set up my precedence constraints based on that. Thanks!

```
    public void Main()

    Dts.Variables["Found"].Value = UrlFound(Dts.Variables["URL1"].Value.ToString());
    Dts.TaskResult = (int)ScriptResults.Success;

    private bool UrlFound(string url)
    {
        try
        {
            //Creating the HttpWebRequest
            HttpWebRequest request = WebRequest.Create(url) as HttpWebRequest;
            //Setting the Request method HEAD, you can also use GET too.
            request.Method = "HEAD";
            //Getting the Web Response.
            HttpWebResponse response = request.GetResponse() as HttpWebResponse;
            //Returns TRUE if the Status code == 200
            response.Close();
            return (response.StatusCode == HttpStatusCode.OK);
        }
        catch
        {
            return false;
        }

    }
```

Comment: I like and have used this approach and am +1 for it workign.  The only thing I did find a nuance that using the component rather than a task outside of dataflow was causing some incorrect responses from one of the servers I was contacting because of the number of records I was processing.  I ended up changing to a task and then threading across a few connections results was faster performance and no blocking from webservers....